# ¿como hacer que el signo de $ aparesca al princio de de cada lista de array?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un ejercio que me pide cambiar las "," por un signo de "$", pero me pide que comienze con el signo de "$" al principio y al final , pero tengo un problema no se como hacer que me aparesca al principio el signo de dolar me gustari un consejo como hacerlo mejor.

```
class Add {

  constructor(...words) {

      this.words = words;

  }

  //tu código va aquí

   print() {

      var f = this.words.toString();

      var reg2 = /\,/g;

      var str = f.replace(reg2,"$");

      console.log(str);
  }

}

var x = new Add("hehe", "hoho", "haha", "hihi", "huhu");

var y = new Add("this", "is", "awesome");

var z = new Add("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", ",", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit");

x.print();

y.print();

z.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto amigo, te va a funcionar muy bien, saludos.

```
class Add {
  constructor(...words) {
      this.words = words;
  }
  //your code goes here
  print () {
      var l = new Array ();
      for (let i in this.words) {
          l.push("$"+this.words[i]);
      }
      //let m = (l.join(""));
      let m = (l.join("")+"$");
      //let m = ('"'+l.join("")+"$"+'"');
      console.log(m);
  }
}

var x = new Add("hehe", "hoho", "haha", "hihi", "huhu");
var y = new Add("this", "is", "awesome");
var z = new Add("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", ",", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit");
x.print();
y.print();
z.print();
```

Comment: muchas gracias  por ayuda